# Showing Dialog using knockoutjs issue with custom binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

today i have come across a knockoutjs code where one check box was there and when user check it then jquery dialog open and when uncheck it then dialog close.
i go through the code and understand bit how it works but one area is not clear.

### here is the HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showDialog" /> Show dialog
<!-- ko template: { if: showDialog, name: 'dialogView' } -->
<!-- /ko -->
<script id="dialogView" type="text/html">
    <div style="display:none" data-bind="dialog: { title: 'Title' }"><p>Some text</p></div>
</script>
```

### here is the full js code

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
        var dialog;

        //do in a setTimeout, so the applyBindings doesn't bind twice from element being copied and moved to bottom
        setTimeout(function() {
            var dlgOptions = { 
                autoOpen: true, 
                close: function(event, ui){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            };            
            $.extend(dlgOptions, options);

            dialog = $(element).clone().dialog(dlgOptions);
        }, 0);

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).dialog("destroy");
            dialog.remove();
        });
    }
};

var viewModel = {
    showDialog: ko.observable(false)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

this below line meaning is not clear

```
<!-- ko template: { if: showDialog, name: 'dialogView' } -->
```

what the code is trying to say like `if showDialog and name is dialogView ?`

when click the check box then **a function is suppose to call** which open dialog box and when uncheck the check box then again a function is suppose to call which close the dialog box. i found no function is associated with checkbox which open and close dialog box but dialog box is opening and closing when checking and unchecking checkbox.

please help me to understand how dialog box is opening and closing when checking and unchecking checkbox. from this jsfiddle link anyone can see the full code
http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/8Cfqz/39/

looking for help and guidance.
thanks

### EDIT

this function `ko.bindingHandlers.dialog` code is not clear to me 
1) when `dialog` function will be called ?
i guess when `showDialog` value will be true then knockout will parse template called `dialogView` and try to bind it and then `dialog()` function will be called.

but the code written inside `dialog()` function is not very clear to me.

so here i like to highlight few lines of code point wise which is not clear to me.

1) what is the meaning of this line `var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};`

2) why `setTimeout()` function is used here ? because without `setTimeout()` dialog options could be set in code.

3) what are the below line about ?

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
    $(element).dialog("destroy");
    dialog.remove();
});
```

4) when `addDisposeCallback()` will be called ?

5) when `init` function in custom binding is called ? does it call one time or every time ?

6) when `update` function in custom binding is called

i often face problem to understand then knockout js custom binding function. so tell me best way to become master of knockout js custom binding.

thanks

Comment: I've added your HTML in to make the question more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) for the `template binding`?

When Knockout runs, it parses the `data-bind` attribute on your virtual HTML element:

```
<!-- ko template: { if: showDialog, name: 'dialogView' } -->
```

The `data-bind` attribute here tells Knockout to render *a* template *if* `ShowDialog` resolves to a true-ish value.

As the documentation says:

> `if` - if this parameter is provided, the template will only be rendered if
>   the specified expression evaluates to true (or a true-ish value). This
>   can be useful for preventing a null observable from being bound
>   against a template before it is populated.

And what should this Knockout binding render? The documentation tells us how to use the `name` parameter:

> `name` - the ID of an element that contains the template you wish to render

So in short, *if* `ShowDialog` returns a true-ish value then Knockout will render whatever it finds in the element referred to in the `name` parameter.

I hope that's clear enough.

### EDIT

To answer your questions:

1) `unwrapObservable` is the long version of the function which can also be called using `unwrap`. Read about it on [this page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

2) I don't know, that's not standard Knockout practice. You'd have to ask the developer who wrote that.

3) If Knockout adds an element to the page then data about the view-model will be cached behind-the-scenes; if you remove this element from the page then you should also tell Knockout to remove that behind-the-scenes data. Have you tried [googling "ko.utils"](https://www.google.ch/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=7rBlVbWJJqPC8gfrmYCwDw&gws_rd=ssl#q=ko.utils)?

4) I think that as far you're concerned, this doesn't matter.

5) Read the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for custom bindings - it clearly explains the `init` callback.

6) Read the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for custom bindings - it clearly explains the `update` callback.

Comment: i just update my question. please see my edit portion and answer me if possible. thanks

Comment: i did not find any similar syntax like `<!-- ko template: { if: showDialog, name: 'dialogView' } -->` from the link u gave here for knockout js doc. so please provide me which give me knowledge about the above syntax

Comment: Then you haven't read the content on the page I linked to. That page contains the documentation for the `template` binding, as well as detailing how to use the `if` and `name` parameters that your example uses. If it still doesn't make sense then I strongly suggest going back to the start of Knockout's documentation and reading from there, or finding a good Knockout tutorial. StackOverflow is not a tutorial-based site, it provides answers to very specific questions.

Comment: how to show the element id from knockout js custom bindning code. i used this code `alert($(element).attr('id'));` inside this function ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {} but does not show the id........where i made the mistake. guide me.

Comment: "guide me" No I won't. You would do well to remember two points: (1) StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site. The better the question, the better the answer.  (2) God helps those who help themselves.   Now go and read the documentation.